# Why multiple threads are able to access a synchronized block?

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronized, illegalmonitorstateexcep

While running this I'm getting `IllegalMonitorStateException` because Even thread is trying to notify when it does not have lock on the object `isEven`. Why is this happening? A thread should only be able to go inside the synchronized block if it has lock on the object.

```
public class NumPrinter implements Runnable{

    public static Boolean isEven = true;
    private boolean isEvenThread;
    private int i;

    public void run() {
    while(i < 100){
     synchronized(isEven){
            boolean notPrinting = (isEven ^ isEvenThread);
            System.out.println(notPrinting);
            if(notPrinting) {
                try {
                    isEven.wait();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }       
            System.out.print(i + ",");
            i = i+2;
            isEven = !isEven;
            isEven.notifyAll();
        }
     }
    }

    public NumPrinter(boolean isEvenThread) {

        this.isEvenThread = isEvenThread;   
        if(isEvenThread)
            i = 0;
        else 
            i = 1;
    }
}

public class MultiThreading {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Thread oddt = new Thread(new NumPrinter(false), "Odd");
        Thread event = new Thread(new NumPrinter(true), "Even");

        event.start();
        oddt.start();


    }
}
```

Comment: Seems that you are doing the same homework as [this guy](http://stackoverflow.com/q/33560337/4856258)...

Comment: NOTE: The purpose of `synchronized` is _not_ to prevent two threads from executing the same code at the same time.  Its purpose is to prevent two threads from accessing the same _data_ at the same time.

Answer (score 2):

It's likely that you need to synchronize/wait/notify on the constant object instead. Also declare the `isEven` as volatile. Finally, put `wait()` call in the loop checking the loop condition as official documentation [recommends](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#wait%28%29):

```
public class NumPrinter implements Runnable {
    private static final Object monitor = new Object();
    private static volatile boolean isEven = true;
    private final boolean isEvenThread;
    private int i;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (i < 100) {
            synchronized (monitor) {
                while (isEven ^ isEvenThread) {
                    try {
                        monitor.wait();
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                System.out.print(i + ",");
                i = i + 2;
                isEven = !isEven;
                monitor.notifyAll();
            }
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: This is an extended and precise version of what I tried to say. Great answer, man.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not an expert in Java, but you rewrite the synchronization token here:

> isEven = !isEven;

It may be not the only problem you have, but use another synchronization token at least (which isn't going to be rewritten).